# How to prepend text to a line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a file with lines of text that looks like this:

```
category1.name1
name2
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
category1   name1
            name2
```

I'm editing this file in VS Code on a Mac. I'm happy to use regex in VS Code, or a command line solution.
I can replace the "." with a tab easily enough, but how do I add tabs to the start of the line if there is no "." in the line?

Comment: Does the `category1` text change - sometimes shorter or sometimes longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a command-line solution using `awk`:

```bash
cat <filename> | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " ");  printf "%-15s%s\n", NF == 1 ? " " : $1, $NF }'
```

You can adjust the width of the first field (the `%-15s` in the `printf`) to something more appropriate as necessary, but otherwise, this seems to fill in what you're looking for.

For example:

```bash
% printf "category1.name1\nname2" | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " ");  printf "%-15s%s\n", NF == 1 ? " " : $1, $NF }'
category1      name1
               name2
```

---

If your heart's set on using tabs, you can use the following modified version, but if the first field is longer than a tab character's width (e.g., eight), things won't line up:

```bash
cat <filename> | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " ");  printf "%s\t%s\n", NF == 1 ? "\t" : $1, $NF }'
```

Comment: I like this answer, but in the end, I was putting way too much energy into a relatively small data set. I did some manual editing in a spreadsheet and sorted it out, but thank you for this response.

Comment: You're most welcome.  Indeed getting the job done over being fancy should win all the time, at least in my opinion.    Great question though; I learned things myself.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this.  I am not sure how uniform your data is try this.

Using an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), you can use javascript in a keybinding to get the lengths of the words you need.  Demo:

[image: pad the middle of a word and align next line demo]

That uses this keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+y",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(^.+?)\\.(.*)\n(^[^\\.\n]+$)",
    "replace": [
      "$${",
        "const len1 = '$1'.length;",  // group 1 length
        "const space = 4;",           // how many spaces to put inside first line
        "const len3 = '$3'.length;",  // group 3 length

        "return '$1'.padEnd(len1 + space, ' ') + '$2' + `\n` + '$3'.padStart(len3  +len1 + space, ' ');",

        "return str;",
      "}$$",
    ],
    "isRegex": true,
    // "restrictFind": "selections"  // use this if you want to limit to selections
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection",
  }
},
```

This uses spaces to align the lines, much easier than tabs.  If it is absolutely necessary to use tabs let me know and I'll see if anything can be done to change this.